# c# directory.getfiles multiple searchpattern

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use the `Directory.GetFiles()` method to retrieve a list of files of multiple search pattern

```
response_201704_1245.1,
response_201704_1245.1.done,
response_201704_1245.12.inpro,
response_201704_1245.450.complete like this.
```

Is there a way to do this in one call?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "response*.*");`

Comment: thank you nino.But i don't need response_201704_1245.1.done,response_201704_1245.12.inpro,response_201704_1245.450.complete files and  also int value frequently increase

Comment: so, you want to include only files that end with int extension, and not those with additional extensions (like done, inpro etc)?

Comment: Yes, you got my point

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with single pattern. But, here's one suggestion to solve that:

```
//regex pattern for a string that ends with dot and one or more digits.
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\.[\d]+$");

//get files, with response*.* pattern and then filter them additionally with regex
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\resp", "response*.*")
    .Where(d => regex.IsMatch(d))
    .ToList();
```